# Xamarin: MarkupExtension not found for i18n:Translate

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I've inherited a Xamarin Forms application. I installed Visual Studio 2015 Professional with Update 2. When I try and run it I get the following error:
**Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 27:7. MarkupExtension not found for i18n:Translate**

Also it appears that the code behind cannot access the controls such as a button or ListView

Comment: Can you paste the incriminated lines?

Answer (score 1):

That looks that the libraries used in your project are not available. 
First, try to restore all nuget packages. If the problem persists, clean the project and rebuild. If that still fails, delete bin and obj folders in each project of your solution and then try again.